# How to kill consumers in activemq

Tags: java, activemq-classic

I am trying to get rid of all of the "Number of Consumers" in a certain queue.  Whenever I purge/delete the queue, the number of consumers still remain if I ever create that queue with the same name again.  Even with 0 pending messages, there are still 6 consumers.

My problem may have stemmed in my java code while not closing the session or connection.

I have tried both restarting and reinstalling the server.

Here is my producer code:

```
 private static String url = ActiveMQConnection.DEFAULT_BROKER_URL;

    public static String addElementToQueue(String queueName,String param1, String param2) throws JMSException, NamingException {
  // Getting JMS connection from the server and starting it
        ConnectionFactory connectionFactory =
                new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(url);
        Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();

// JMS messages are sent and received using a Session. We will
        // create here a non-transactional session object. If you want
        // to use transactions you should set the first parameter to 'true'
        Session session = connection.createSession(false,
                Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

        // Destination represents here our queue on the
        // JMS server. You don't have to do anything special on the
        // server to create it, it will be created automatically.
        Destination destination = session.createQueue(queueName);

        // MessageProducer is used for sending messages (as opposed
        // to MessageConsumer which is used for receiving them)
        MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(destination);   

        String queueMessage = param1+ "-" + param2;

        TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage(queueMessage);

        // Here we are sending the message!
        producer.send(message);

        connection.close();
        session.close();      // added after problem came up
        producer.close();     // added after problem came up

        return commandID;
}
```

Here is my consumer code:

```
 // URL of the JMS server
    private static String url = ActiveMQConnection.DEFAULT_BROKER_URL;

    public static Pair consumeNextElement(String queueName) throws JMSException {
        // Getting JMS connection from the server
        ConnectionFactory connectionFactory
                = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(url);
        Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
        connection.start();   

        // Creating session for seding messages
        Session session = connection.createSession(false,
                Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

        // Getting the queue
        Destination destination = session.createQueue(queueName);

        // MessageConsumer is used for receiving (consuming) messages
        MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(destination);


        // Here we receive the message.
        // By default this call is blocking, which means it will wait
        // for a message to arrive on the queue.
        Message message = consumer.receive();

        // There are many types of Message and TextMessage
        // is just one of them. Producer sent us a TextMessage
        // so we must cast to it to get access to its .getText()
        // method.

        String[] parts = ((TextMessage)message).getText().split("-");
        Pair retVal = new Pair(parts[0], parts[1]);

        connection.close();
        session.close();        // added after problem came up
        consumer.close();      // added after problem came up  

        return retVal;
    }
```

Any thoughts?

Thanks.

Comment: My edits contain consumer/producer code.  thanks.

Comment: what is the use case that would require you to kill the consumers after purging a queue?

Comment: Right now we have a queue "abc" which is broken.  We can push items onto the queue.  However, the server times out when we try to consume the queue.  This only happened for queue "abc" and no other queue that we have.  This is also the only queue with 6 consumers on it.  The others have 0 consumers.  This leads us to think that the open connections on this queue are blocking us from consuming elements.  Therefore, we are trying to manually kill the open connections.

Comment: We had multiple servers using the same queue.  We had to restart all servers to fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of consumers is the number of listeners on the queue.  Purging the queue should only remove the enqueued messages - those consumers listening will be unaffected.

The ability of the consumer to maintain/re-establish a connection may depend on the transport used to connect, and [settings for the transport](http://activemq.apache.org/configuring-transports.html) may allow for some tweaking of connection properties.

I frankly don't have much experience with these, but you might investigate [Advisory Messages](http://activemq.apache.org/advisory-message.html) as a means to help debug your connections.  The JMX interface or web console don't appear to be helpful beyond reporting consumer counts.