# Kill consumer in activemq?

Tags: java, activemq-classic

On ActiveMQ broker, I write a plugin to filter devices' connections. 
In this plugin, I want to delete a destination and all consumers connected that destination. I use AdvisoryBroker to get all connectionInfo , destinationInfo, consumerInfo. Then, I use functions (removeConsumer, removeDestination, removeConnection) to remove the suitable destination.

My problem is : Although when to check by jConsole, destination and consumers are removed but consumer's connection is still "exist".

"Exist" is : I use mosquitto_sub to sub to a destination and this connection isn't interrupted. I also have tried stop broker.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to kill consumers in activemq](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13262942/how-to-kill-consumers-in-activemq)

Comment: @AnanthaRajuC : that topic doesn't help to solve this problem. When I use AdvisoryBroker and debug by jConsole , this problem occurs.